# turtle showing error which used to work fine earlier

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.forward(100)
t.done()
```

1. this code is returning an error like this
   NameError: name 'turtle' is not defined
2. I have tried to use turtle but it doesn't seem to be working the way it is shown in the code.
3. I have tried referring to various sources but could not find the fix

Comment: I don't see how the code you gave can throw that error. Please provide a [mcve] as well as the actual traceback that you get when you run it.

Comment: try to run some demo script by using: $. python -m turtledemo.bytedesign if you get a traceback then python cant acces turle for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies on this line:

```
t.done()
```

You see, you defined `t` as a [`Turtle` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.Turtle), and `Turtle` objects have no attribute `done`.

The `done()` attribute belongs to the `turtle` module itself, so instead of `t.done()`, it's `turtle.done()`:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.forward(100)
turtle.done()
```